# Find the highest completed stage

Tags: sql, group-by

[image: Table Data]

I have above data which lists the stages and their order and the avg completion. I would like to get the stage beyond which there are no uncompleted stages. For example, from the above data the highest stage that is completed is STAGEID -12 as STAGEID - 14 is not 100% complete which disqualifies the stages beyond it to be not considered as completed as well. If all of the stages are 100% complete then get the highest stage that is completed. Any thoughts on how to query for it would be really helpful.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

```
select MAX(STAGEID)
from [Your-table]
where average=100;
```

Comment: Hi Jibin, StageID is unique, and I am looking to get the stageid beyond which there are no incomplete stages. If I only get stages that are 100% complete, how do I know which is the stage beyond which there are no imcomplete stages. I will always end of picking the stage with highest order and it might not be the right one.

Comment: @srikanth964 I have updated my answer my answer.For a better solution you need to post your table structure and sample data.

Comment: @srikanth964, Can I know what's your expected result for that table data??

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume table name is 'stages':

```
select min(s.stageid) 
    from stages s1 
       where 1 = (select count(*) 
                      from stages s2 
                         where s1.stageid <s2.stageid and s2.average <> 100 and s1.average=100 and s2.stageorder = s.stageorder+1);
```